# Joining add and edit in one route

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm wondering weather I can join two routes into one - add and edit.
Here are my states:

```
.state('app.topics.add', {
    url: 'add/',
    views: {
        'page@app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/sites/topics/add.html',
            controller: 'topicsaddCtrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('app.topics.details', {
    url: '{topic_id:[0-9]+}/',
    views: {
        'page@app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/sites/topics/details.html',
            controller: 'topicsdetailsCtrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('app.topics.details.edit', {
    url: 'edit/',
    views: {
        'page@app': {
            templateUrl: 'app/sites/topics/add.html',
            controller: 'topicsaddCtrl',
        }
    }
})
```

`topic/add/` - adding topic
`topic/2/` - details of topic
`topic/2/edit/` - editing topic
But state for add and edit are using the same templates and controllers. Can I simplyfy states?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stateParams https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

```
.state('app.topics.add', {
            url: ':method/:id',
            views: {
                'page@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/sites/topics/add.html',
                    controller: 'topicsaddCtrl',
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                formData: ['$stateParams', 'topicSvc', function ($stateParams, topicSvc) {
                    if ($stateParams.method === 'add') {
                        return {}; //return empty object if you creating topic
                    } else if ($stateParams.method === 'edit' && $stateParams.id) {
                        return topicSvc.getDetail($stateParams.id); //get topic data from topicSvc service
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
```

Also you can inject $stateParams to your controller and access its 'method' and 'id' property.